# Python code snippet to be used in PHP

Tags: c#, php, python, web

I am a Microsoft developer then I explain what I want to do in those words to everybody to understand the question better.

I have a Python piece of code which I need to make a little website and have the interface for the program to accept one text and return the result in another.

So if I wanted to do this in Visual Studio, I would create the interface I wanted in `Xaml` and using binding I would write the core in `C#`. However instead of C# code I have a ready `Python` snippet and I don't want to rework it to the `C` code. How can I do the same using `Python` and per say `PHP` or any other.

PS, I have the PHP ready in my Linux machine and there is no database involved in this. quite simple snippet.

Detailed answers will be appreciated, however you don't need to necessarily and if you show me the right direction I'll dig it up.

Comment: Despite the question is very well written, it's still unclear for me. What does your Python code contain and what your PHP code want to contain? Do you have a full logic and gui written on python and you want to port to web, or you have just something like a web service in python and want to query it via PHP?

Comment: No not at all. very simple example to explain. Say my Python code accepts a string 'Test' and adds 's' to the end and returns 'Tests'. All I need to have a interface on the web (locally) to pass that string from User to the Python code and return it's result to me then I can show. Definitely if I can figure this out I have enough programing and HTML experience to add the bells and whistles. (I hope :) )

Comment: Oh, understand. Then you need to take look at `exec()` -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php . If, for example, you python script accepts the input from the standard input as param i.e. `myscript.py Test`, then you do in php `exec("myscript.py Test", $output);` and afterwards check `$output`. To put `Test` from user iput you can user the request (beware someone can inject code into your exec statement) e.g. `$var = $_POST['var']; exec("myscript.py $var", $output);`

Comment: Ofcrouse, I think, in order to exec python script, you will need to have alias of your python binary or fullpath like `exec("usr/local/bin/python /home/user/scripts/myscript.py $var", $output);`

Comment: I understand. Since this is going to be for an internal use to ease the process of dealing with the Python code i am not quite worried about security side of it. I will give this a go and I am pretty sure it'll do since it looks fairly trivial. Thanks again

Comment: if you wish you can put it as an answer then I will mark it right. I bet it'll be useful for some others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

So if you made your Python code to accept the input as an argument using

```
import sys
myPythonInputVar = sys.argv[1]
```

then you can feed it as in input argument to the line that you want to execute in the syntax form below in `PHP`

```
<html>
<body>
   Your Python code returns: 
       <?php echo exec("/usr/bin/python /home/myUsername/test.py $myInput");?>
</body>
</html>
```