# How to call python in PHP on windows environment

Tags: php, python

I need to call python program in php.I need to display the output in browser.
What are all setup i have to done to run python in php program on windows OS.
Please provide me some simple sample codes.I already went over many forums and questions,I cant understand How to perform this action exactly.Can anybody explain it to me briefly,so that i will have good understanding.I already went through functions such as

```
Exec()
Popen()
```

what is difference between this two? and what are all the ways there to get this done.Please help me to get sense of this.Any help would be appreciated.

I dont have any knowledge about python and intermediate level in PHP.

Comment: what did go wrong when using exec? P.S.: the most recent duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464677/python-code-snippet-to-be-used-online

Comment: I dont got any output.I may doing something wrong.Can you explain it with little sample program.I have tried something like this,

$sample=exec('python test.py');
print_r($sample);

Comment: you need to pass a second parameter where the output is `exec("mycommand", $output);` then in $output will be what you expect (as an array maybe)

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php http://php.net/popen

Comment: @RoyalBg that helped me little.by the way,What is the difference between theses two.@Marc thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$output = shell_exec("C:\\wamp64\\www\\mechmarcl\\assets\\documents\\threadsearch.py");
```

if you want to pass some data in to the python script you can use

```
$output = shell_exec("C:\\wamp64\\www\\mechmarcl\\assets\\documents\\threadsearch.py 
$sym");
```